# roots of the discrete Fourier transform of a polynomial

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $p(x)= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$, $q(x)= b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ be two polynomials with complex coefficients. if $(b_0,b_1,b_2,...,b_{n-1})$ is the discrete Fourier transform of $(a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1})$ can we say anything about the *roots* of $q(x)$ if we know the *roots* of $p(x)$. I'm mainly interested in relations between the roots of $p$ and $q$ where $a_j$'s are positive integers. In this case  $b_j=$ conjugate$(b_{n-j})$ for all meaningful $j$.

Comment: $a_k,k=0 \ldots n-1$ is the discrete Fourier transform of $p_m =\frac{1}{n} p(e^{2i \pi m/n}), m = 0 \ldots n-1$.

Comment: There is certainly a relation, because knowing the roots of $p$, you can reconstruct $p$, then its DFT $q$ and the roots of $q$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thank you very much for your answer . It seems to suggest that there are no insightful relations between roots of p and q. BTW aren't there some typos in your post ? i.e. I would say r0+r1+r2+r3 = -a3/a4.

Comment: @khoramdin: you are right about the ratio. But not about the minus sign (see my remark). The ratio makes things even harder.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of a polynomial are related to its coefficients by Vieta's relations.

For the fourth degree,

$$a_0=r_0+r_1+r_2+r_3,$$
$$a_1=r_0r_1+r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_0,$$
$$a_2=r_0r_1r_2+r_0r_2r_3+r_1r_0r_2+r_1r_2r_3+r_2r_0r_1+r_2r_1r_3,$$
$$a_3=r_0r_1r_2r_3$$

where for convenience we used the opposite of the root values.

Then taking the DFT and expressing the new coefficients in terms of the roots of the DFT, we get four relations

$$(r_0+r_1+r_2+r_3)+(r_0r_1+r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_0)+(r_0r_1r_2+r_0r_2r_3+r_1r_0r_2+r_1r_2r_3+r_2r_0r_1+r_2r_1r_3)+r_0r_1r_2r_3=s_0+s_1+s_2+s_3$$

$$(r_0+r_1+r_2+r_3)+i(r_0r_1+r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_0)-(r_0r_1r_2+r_0r_2r_3+r_1r_0r_2+r_1r_2r_3+r_2r_0r_1+r_2r_1r_3)-ir_0r_1r_2r_3=s_0s_1+s_1s_2+s_2s_3+s_3s_0$$

$$(r_0+r_1+r_2+r_3)-(r_0r_1+r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_0)+(r_0r_1r_2+r_0r_2r_3+r_1r_0r_2+r_1r_2r_3+r_2r_0r_1+r_2r_1r_3)-r_0r_1r_2r_3=s_0s_1s_2+s_0s_2s_3+s_1s_0s_2+s_1s_2s_3+s_2s_0s_1+s_2s_1s_3$$

$$(r_0+r_1+r_2+r_3)-i(r_0r_1+r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_0)-(r_0r_1r_2+r_0r_2r_3+r_1r_0r_2+r_1r_2r_3+r_2r_0r_1+r_2r_1r_3)+ir_0r_1r_2r_3=s_0s_1s_2s_3$$

I can't see a way to simplify this.

Unless there is some simplification due to the particular expression of the coefficients, in general it is not even possible to express the $s_k$ in terms of the $r_k$ in general, as the resolution of algebraic equations can't be done with closed-form expressions.

Comment: Your notations are unclear. Did you read my comment above ? $b_{n-m} = \frac{1}{n} p(e^{2i \pi m/n})$ in OP's question

Comment: @reuns: $e^{2i\pi/4}=i$.